# Appium - wait for webview to load

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am using Appium 1.0.0, and my test is (using Ruby):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'
capabilities = {
    deviceName: 'iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit)',
    platformName: 'iOS',
    platformVersion: '7.1',
    app: '/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXX.app'
}

server_url = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"

Appium::Driver.new(caps: capabilities).start_driver

Appium.promote_appium_methods Object

find_element(:name, "InitAll ShowIS").click

--here I want to wait for WEBVIEW_1 to load    

set_context "WEBVIEW_1"
find_element(:xpath, "//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[2]/UIAWebView[1]").click
driver_quit
```

I cannot make my test wait for 'WEBVIEW_1' to be loaded. I tried `wait` and `wait_true` and many other options I found [here](https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/blob/master/docs/ios_docs.md), none of them work for me (struggling with this for several hours now...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have same issue

Answer (score -1):

For webview you cannot access your element which you find through appium inspector. Instead get the page source access  the element as shown below

```
findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstName']"))
```